# How to align chemical reactions in multiple environments?

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemistry, eqnarray

How do I align (by arrow) chemical reactions in different environments (between text)?

Example: Two arrays.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    A & \longrightarrow & A' \\
    B & \longrightarrow & B'
\end{eqnarray}

some text

\begin{eqnarray}
    C & \longrightarrow & C' \\
    D & \longrightarrow & D'
\end{eqnarray}
```

For A/B and C/D the centering works. But they are not all (A,B,C,D) centered.

How do I manage this problem?

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  It's great to include your code, but please include it as part of a minimal working example, which will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid `eqnarray` and use `amsmath`'s `align` instead, [see the reasons here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Then I'd use `amsmath`'s  `\intertext` if the text between the reaction is short *and* the reactions form some sort of set. If they don't or if the text is too long then alignment might not be so important after all or even look strange.

And last but not least I'd use `chemformula` for the chemistry:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \ch{A & -> NO_{$x$}} \\
  \ch{B & -> H2O} \\
  \intertext{some text}
  \ch{C & -> SO4^{2-}} \\
  \ch{D & -> NH4+}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you want your reactions numbered independently from equations then you can do the same thing with `chemmacros`' `reactions` environment – this also uses `chemformula` for the chemicals:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  A & -> NO_{$x$} \\
  B & -> H2O
  \intertext{some text}
  C & -> SO4^{2-} \\
  D & -> NH4+
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you, but the text is a short paragraph. I think it would be nice when the reactions are aligned well. Can I manage this?

Comment: @matt Just write the short paragraph with `\intertext` as I did in my answer :)

Comment: ok thank you I will try it immediately!