# Misunderstanding reactions environment of chemmacros v. 5.10

Tags: packages, compilation-error, chemmacros

I wanted to give my answer to this question

[How to align chemical reactions in multiple environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528548/how-to-align-chemical-reactions-in-multiple-environments)

with the environment reactions into the manual of [chemmacros](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros/chemmacros-manual.pdf). I think always that my low level to understand English language is my Achilles' heel.

My apologies to the author of the package Clemens Niederberger of `chemmacros`
v5.10 2020/02/03 for this question. I have seen your guide to the pag. 43:

[image]

But how does the `reactions` environment operate? I don't understand it. For this MWE I have an error:

> ! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'chemmacros/reactions/before-tag' is unknown and is
>   (LaTeX3)        being ignored.
>   For immediate help type H .
>    ...
>
> l.10  }
>
> ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros} %%%%% <---- or chemformula?
\chemsetup[reactions]{
 before-tag =  , %%%%<----automatic number without bold characther
 tag-open = ( ,
 tag-close = )
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{reactions}
 A + 2 B &-> 3 C + D "\label{rxn:test}"
\intertext{Some text in between aligned reactions}
 E + F &<=> G + 1/2 H
\end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to load `chemmacros` with the `reactions` module.

Comment: @cgnieder Hi, I have put after `\begin{document}` the macro `\chemsetup[reactions]{
 before-tag =  , %%%%<----automatic number without bold characther
 tag-open = ( ,
 tag-close = )
 }` but I have an error: The key chemmacros/reactions/before-tag' is unknown and is [ }]. Please, can I have an answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: I see that. But what you do not do is load the module `reactions` which defines the environment and the options.

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum**: *I leave this post to remember my mistake for the next time.*

---

After the comment of the very good user @cgnieder, excuse me again with the author of the package. I have not read to the begin of the manual that needed to be loaded `\usechemmodule{all}` or the specific module `\usechemmodule{reactions}`. I'm very happy to compile himself the code. Thank you very much @cgnieder.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\chemsetup[reactions]{
 before-tag =  ,
 tag-open = ( ,
 tag-close = )
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
 A + 2 B &-> 3 C + D "\label{rxn:test}"
\intertext{After many attempts I was been able to compile it :-)}
 E + F &<=> G + 1/2 H
\end{reactions}
\end{document}
```